# Why isn't my request working with orWhereRaw()?

Tags: php, sql, laravel, eloquent

I have a search field that looks into different values to check if there is anything that match what I inputed. It works fine with the email, first and last name. However, when I try to put the phone_number using `->orWhereRaw()` to remove some characters, nothing is returned. However, when I do the same request directly to the database, it works just fine.

Can you help me figure this out?

Controller code:

```
            $candidates->where(function ($query) use ($request) {
                $query->where('email', 'like', "%$request->search%")
                ->orWhere('first_name', 'like', "%$request->search%")
                ->orWhere('last_name', 'like', "%$request->search%")
                ->orWhereRaw("replace(replace(replace(phone_number, ' ', ''), '-', ''), '#', '') LIKE '?'", array("%$request->search%"));
```

Query according to Telescope:

```
select
  *
from
  `candidates`
where
  (
    `email` like '%23%'
    or `first_name` like '%23%'
    or `last_name` like '%23%'
    or replace(
      replace(replace(phone_number, ' ', ''), '-', ''),
      '#',
      ''
    ) LIKE '?'
  )
```

According to `$query->dd()`, the bindings are set correctly.

I really don't see why the part with the phone numbers doesn't work...

Comment: have you tried using `orWhere(DB::raw("replace(replace(replace(phone_number, ' ', ''), '-', ''), '#', '') LIKE '?'", array("%$request->search%"));` ? of course `use DB;`

Comment: `$phoneNumber = $request->input('phone_number');  $sanitizedPhoneNumber = str_replace([' ', '-'], '', $phoneNumber);` then use `$sanitizedPho...`. if a normal orWhere, assuming it comes from `$request->`

Comment: @Ballard DB::raw doesn't work either and I don't want to sanitize my input, I want to sanitize what is in the database in the field "phone_number".